# Get same values with Math.random

Tags: javascript, function

In the below code, I want to `function 2` to change the text in `text` to complete the cycle. Unfortunately var `rand` will not change `text` into being a different word. Rather it will always remain same the whole time.

```
var x = 0;

function function1() {
    document.getElementById("text").textContent = rand;
}

function function2() {
    if (document.getElementById("text").innerHTML === "Red") {
        x += 1;
        document.getElementById("text2").textContent = x;
        function1();
    }
}

//I have got the equivalent functions for blue, green and gold as well   
var randomarray = ['Red', 'Blue', 'Green', 'Gold', ];
var rand = randomarray[Math.floor(Math.random() * randomarray.length)];
```

Can someone please show me how to fix this.

Comment: It's unclear to me what you are asking: the sentences don't make much sense grammatically. Please reformulate your problem.

Comment: Well, you never change `rand`. You set it once and that's it. If you want `rand` to change you have to change it.

Comment: The same way that you initialized it. `rand = randomarray[Math.floor(Math.random() * randomarray.length)];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the declaration of rand to inside function1. That way it does indeed chose
a again a color each time function1 is called

```
function function1() {
var rand = randomarray[Math.floor(Math.random() * randomarray.length)];
document.getElementById("text").textContent = rand;
}
```

and comment out (or remove) the declaration you have outside both functions as it becomes irrelevant.

```
//var rand = randomarray[Math.floor(Math.random() * randomarray.length)];
```

Comment: @ZAZLEO I didn't say that this doesn't work, I'm just trying to have some quality answers en SO..

Comment: @JoaquínO Some questions really doesn't need/deserve much explanation. SO has plenty of such cases. That said, I do sympathize with your point and added a brief comment. Thanks.

Comment: @MASL if the OP didn't know how to do this, the best way to make him/her understand what he/she's doing is with some explanation. Otherwise, it may be just some copy&paste with no acquisition of knowledge.. PS. thanks for the edit :)

Comment: @JoaquínO I got point already before. Trust me. There is no absolutes here when it comes to teaching though. Sometimes, a challenging answer might be more enlightening than a detailed explanation. Of course, knowing to balance both is an art. And I'm not gonna claim to master that though.